# android manifest giving error only for activity

Tags: android-manifest

I am developing a project on face recognition in android. But my androidmanifest file is having errors. The errors are only for the activities that i have created. It says that cannot resolve the symbol (activity_name).[This is the snapshot of my manifest file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZQRh.png) I have tried cleaning up the project and cache but nothing works out. Also it showing "Cannot resolve symbol R" in all the places where i have used it(say R.Layout.Activity_main).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove package in manifest tag

Wrong :
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
    package=“**package** com.example.jhimanshu.samples” >

Updated :
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
    package=“com.example.jhimanshu.samples” >

If it does not fix share your app source code package structure, we need to check both your package structure and your declared one in manifest are matching.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That error was rectified but i am still getting the error that "Cannot resolve the symbol R".

Comment: Try clean and build, if it's not working you might have some compiling issues which prevents generation of R file.

Comment: Thank you once again. It got rectified.